# R: Combine character columns of data.frame into one vector

Tags: r, string, dataframe, character

I am working with R and trying to combine two character columns of the data frame into one vector. Let us say, here is my data

```
a = c("one", "two", "three")
b = c("four", "five", "six")
data = data.frame(a,b)
```

Now I try

```
c(data$a, data$b)
```

or

```
c(data[,"a"], data[,"b"])
```

Both give me 
     `[1] 1 3 2 2 1 3`

What is this?

I would expect and I want the same output as from

```
c(a,b)
```

namely `[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"  "five"  "six"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your columns are factors. Convert to characters, and it would work as you expect:

```
> data[] <- lapply(data, as.character)
> c(data$a, data$b)
[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"  "five"  "six"
```

Of course, you could always do:

```
> as.character(unlist(data))
[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"  "five"  "six"
```

Comment: Thank you. +1. With two simultaneously arrived answers it is _really_  hard  to decide which one to accept.

Comment: In my real problem I start with the data frame (not two vectors like a small reproducible example in the question). So I decided that knowing how to transform the data frame to character helped me more.

Answer (score 2):

When you're creating your dataframe your vectors are being stored as factors, not characters. You have to specify that you want characters with

```
 data = data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Thank you. +1. With two simultaneously arrived answers it is _really_  hard  to decide which one to accept.

Comment: @lanenok, this answer addresses the problem at the source while my answer provides a solution if you encounter such a problem. Thus, they are conceptually different, and you should use that conceptual difference to decide which is most applicable to your situation.